# Group by Date bigger than SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, group-by

I'm working with Micrososft SqlServer 2012 and I have this table:

**Table**

```
+-----------+--------+------------+
| Id_Client | Amount | Date       |
+-----------+--------+------------+
| 1         | 100    | 24/08/2015 |
| 2         | 100    | 24/07/2015 |
| 3         | 100    | 24/06/2015 |
| 3         | 100    | 24/05/2015 |
+-----------+--------+------------+
```

And I need to make a query like this:

**Query**

```
SELECT ID_CLIENT, 
CASE WHEN DATE <= '01/07/2015' THEN 'OLD' ELSE 'NEW' END,
SUM(AMOUNT) FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY ID_CLIENT
```

How do I Group by Date with the condition, instead of each Date?
I expect something like:

**Expected result**

```
+---+-----+-----+
| 1 | NEW | 100 |
| 2 | NEW | 100 |
| 3 | OLD | 200 |
+---+-----+-----+
```

Comment: `GROUP BY ID_CLIENT, CASE WHEN DATE <= '01/07/2015' THEN 'OLD' ELSE 'NEW' END`

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't know that

Comment: @Lamak you should post it as an answer

Comment: @Y.S I would prefer to close this question since it was answered on a comment. And I'm not comfortable answering a question which I already voted to close